# Ruby: parsing dates from arabic characters?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have a rails app that receives dates from an ios app. One user has been posting dates that look like this: "٢٠١٢-٠٥-٠١ ٠٩:٤٠:٣٨ +0000". And when ruby tries to take that string and parse a date out of it, it crashes. Any clues on how to deal with these kinds of strings in either my rails app or the ios app (which I can't touch, but a friend maintains)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#encoding: utf-8

puts "٢٠١٢-٠٥-٠١ ٠٩:٤٠:٣٨ +0000".tr('٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩', '0123456789')
#=>2012-05-01 09:40:38 +0000
```

Comment: works fine in ruby 1.9.3, but in 1.8.7 I get this as output: `95919395-9199-9193 9199:9991:9799 +0000`

Comment: I kinda forgot how to do utf-8 with 1.8.7 . Something with running Ruby with  option -KU to setup $KCODE for utf-8 . Maybe @Marc-André Lafortune 's Backport gem can help you out.

Comment: thanks, I'm actually moving my codebase to a platform with ruby 1.9 so I expect the original solution to work ;)